# How to retrieve 256 element array to mongodb?

Tags: java, mongodb

I have a collection data format like this,
I now transmit and _id and line. How to return 256 element array
Ex: transmit _id: 4 line 1045, return line from (1045-256) to 1045

```
{
  "_id" : 1,
  "fingerprint" : [ 
    {
        "line" : 1,
        "sub_finger" : "00000000"
    }, 
    {
        "line" : 2,
        "sub_finger" : "00000000"
    }, 
    {
        "line" : 3,
        "sub_finger" : "00000000"
    }, 
    {
        "line" : 4,
        "sub_finger" : "00000000"
    }, 
    {
        "line" : 5,
        "sub_finger" : "00000000"
    }, ...
```

Comment: You can try `db.collection.find( { _id:4 }, { fingerprint: { $slice: [ 1045-256, 256 ] } } )`

Comment: i'm try but not activity, thanks Veeram

Comment: You are welcome. What error did you get ? Can I see your query ?

Comment: Woa, it run, i do not understand what happened: v: v it's in MongoShell.
If you know about java + mongo. Can i ask you ?? Used in nodeJS has API library query also in java i do not know.?

Comment: I am doing a project on song identification. The database is complete. To the query step is a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below code in with mongodb java driver.

```
 MongoClient client = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
 MongoDatabase database = client.getDatabase("test");
 MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("collection");
 Document result = collection.find(Filters.eq("_id", 4)).projection(Projections.slice("fingerprint", 1045-256, 256)).first()
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/), [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/), [$sort](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/), [$skip](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/skip/) and [$limit](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/) in mongodb aggregation pipeline we can achieve this

MongoDB shell Query

db.mycollection.aggregate([{$unwind:"$fingerprint"}, {$match: {_id:4}}, {$sort: {line:1}}, {$skip:1045}, {$limit:256}]);

> Explanation - How this query works

$unwind - Unwinds the fingerprint array into individual documents

$match - Matches the required documents and moves it to the next level in aggregation pipeline (Filters the collection and helps in delivering faster)

$sort - Sort the unwinded documents in ascending order (We need this, otherwise we may miss few documents on using Skip and limit)

$skip - Need to skip the documents which we have rendered already

$limit - Limits the size of the result

Example

Let us have a collection with 3 records

```
db.mycollection.find()

[{
  "_id" : 1,
  "fingerprint" : [ 
    {
        "line" : 1,
        "sub_finger" : "00000000"
    }, 
    {
        "line" : 2,
        "sub_finger" : "00000000"
    }, 
    {
        "line" : 3,
        "sub_finger" : "00000000"
    }, 
    {
        "line" : 4,
        "sub_finger" : "00000000"
    }, 
    {
        "line" : 5,
        "sub_finger" : "00000000"
    }]
},
{
  "_id" : 2,
  "fingerprint" : [ 
    {
        "line" : 1,
        "sub_finger" : "00000000"
    }, 
    {
        "line" : 2,
        "sub_finger" : "00000000"
    }, 
    {
        "line" : 3,
        "sub_finger" : "00000000"
    }, 
    {
        "line" : 4,
        "sub_finger" : "00000000"
    }, 
    {
        "line" : 5,
        "sub_finger" : "00000000"
    }]
},
{
  "_id" : 3,
  "fingerprint" : [ 
    {
        "line" : 1,
        "sub_finger" : "00000000"
    }, 
    {
        "line" : 2,
        "sub_finger" : "00000000"
    }, 
    {
        "line" : 3,
        "sub_finger" : "00000000"
    }, 
    {
        "line" : 4,
        "sub_finger" : "00000000"
    }, 
    {
        "line" : 5,
        "sub_finger" : "00000000"
    }]
}]
```

Let us use the aggregation pipeline to get the desired result

```
db.mycollection.aggregate([{$unwind:"$fingerprint"}])

{ "_id" : 1, "fingerprint" : { "line" : 1, "sub_finger" : "00000000" } }
{ "_id" : 1, "fingerprint" : { "line" : 2, "sub_finger" : "00000000" } }
{ "_id" : 1, "fingerprint" : { "line" : 3, "sub_finger" : "00000000" } }
{ "_id" : 1, "fingerprint" : { "line" : 4, "sub_finger" : "00000000" } }
{ "_id" : 1, "fingerprint" : { "line" : 5, "sub_finger" : "00000000" } }
{ "_id" : 2, "fingerprint" : { "line" : 1, "sub_finger" : "00000000" } }
{ "_id" : 2, "fingerprint" : { "line" : 2, "sub_finger" : "00000000" } }
{ "_id" : 2, "fingerprint" : { "line" : 3, "sub_finger" : "00000000" } }
{ "_id" : 2, "fingerprint" : { "line" : 4, "sub_finger" : "00000000" } }
{ "_id" : 2, "fingerprint" : { "line" : 5, "sub_finger" : "00000000" } }
{ "_id" : 3, "fingerprint" : { "line" : 1, "sub_finger" : "00000000" } }
{ "_id" : 3, "fingerprint" : { "line" : 2, "sub_finger" : "00000000" } }
{ "_id" : 3, "fingerprint" : { "line" : 3, "sub_finger" : "00000000" } }
{ "_id" : 3, "fingerprint" : { "line" : 4, "sub_finger" : "00000000" } }
{ "_id" : 3, "fingerprint" : { "line" : 5, "sub_finger" : "00000000" } }
```

$unwind - unwinded the collection and now we have 15 documents

```
db.mycollection.aggregate([{$unwind:"$fingerprint"}, {$match: {_id:1}}])

Note: Pass the respective document id in the $match query

{ "_id" : 1, "fingerprint" : { "line" : 1, "sub_finger" : "00000000" } }
{ "_id" : 1, "fingerprint" : { "line" : 2, "sub_finger" : "00000000" } }
{ "_id" : 1, "fingerprint" : { "line" : 3, "sub_finger" : "00000000" } }
{ "_id" : 1, "fingerprint" : { "line" : 4, "sub_finger" : "00000000" } }
{ "_id" : 1, "fingerprint" : { "line" : 5, "sub_finger" : "00000000" } }
```

$skip - To Skip documents
$limit - To limit the final result

```
db.mycollection.aggregate([{$unwind:"$fingerprint"}, {$match: {_id:1}},{$sort: {line:1}}, {$skip:1}, {$limit:2}]);

{ "_id" : 1, "fingerprint" : { "line" : 2, "sub_finger" : "00000000" } }
{ "_id" : 1, "fingerprint" : { "line" : 3, "sub_finger" : "00000000" } }
```

Note that I have skipped 1 document and limitted my result as 2 documents

Hope it Helps!

Comment: Really thank you, it is very useful. Thanks Clement Amarnath

Comment: I tried with my database and the results were very messy, and use java very difficult

Comment: and number records very large